# Which of the two variables that are correlated should I eliminate?

Tags: modeling

I want to run a binary logistic regression.
After pearson test I have 2 correlated variables, one continuous and one categorical. I guess I should eliminate categorical variable. But I want to know the theory of eliminating correlated variables.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Does this answer your question? [Using VIF (variance inflation factor) to reduce the data set and account for multicollinearity decreases the r2 and the performance of my model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/604708/using-vif-variance-inflation-factor-to-reduce-the-data-set-and-account-for-mul) It is not clear that you should eliminate either variable, as the link shows can be damaging.

Comment: I want to avoid overfitting so I have to eliminate correlated variable. Between A and B how can I choose?

Comment: As you can see from the link, there is no guarantee that this is a good strategy that will improve model performance. You might wind up getting worse performance (even out-of-sample) by eliminating one of the variables than you by keeping both.

Comment: You are right, particularly my sample size is small.. I should save information for better modeling.